# Using twilio to send SMS with Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, twilio

I am trying to send a message from android ( kotlin ) using Twilio AP.

I added the twilio library

`implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.17.+"`

and here is my kotlin class :

```
package com.example.new_pharma_project

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val client = TwilioRestClient.Builder (
            "username",
            "passowrd"
        ).build()


        val message = Message.creator(
            PhoneNumber("+213777875776"),
            PhoneNumber("+213777877556"),
            "Ahoy from Twilio"
        ).create(client)

        println(message.sid)
    }
}
```

I expected to receive a message on my phone but here is what I'm getting in the log output

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)`

Comment: didn't notice thank you. by the way don't you have any solution for that ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with twillio SDK unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We strongly recommend that you do not use the Twilio API SDK in Android applications. To do so, you would need to embed or use your Twilio credentials within your application which leaves them vulnerable to a malicious user who could decompile the application, steal the credentials and abuse your account.

Instead, we recommend that you create a server side application that you can use to proxy your API requests from your application to the Twilio API. [Here is an example of how to do that (using Java, I'm afraid)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html). Hopefully you can apply that to Kotlin too.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yeah, I used a server-side application using node.js and it worked perfectly. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Android library I've made for TwilioSMS without the need for server-side apps.
https://github.com/hihi-dev/android-twilio-sms

Runs on API 14 +

```
implementation 'com.github.hihi-dev:twiliosms:0.1.1'
```